# Pipe sound output to file?

Tags: recording, audio

Is there a way to either pipe the sound output of the computer to a file or record what the computer puts out? I know I could use a headphone to microphone cord, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Google doesn't give very good results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Audio Hijack Pro](http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) which can record any audio you can hear on your computer. Free to try.

There's also the cheaper, simpler [Piezo](http://rogueamoeba.com/piezo/) from the same company.

Comment: @CoffeeRain Glad I could help! =)

Comment: There is now a cheaper version of Audio Hijack with simpler features that you can buy for US $10. It is called Piezo. http://goo.gl/kzGWD

Comment: @WheatWilliams: Thanks, I've edited in your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

These days, I prefer the [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) virtual audio driver, together with its [Multi-Output Device](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/wiki/Multi-Output-Device), which can, for example, mix your regular computer audio with Blackhole to record (Blackhole) and listen (to the regular computer audio) simultaneously.